# Where to learn about z3 theorem prover APIs for c++?

Tags: c++, logic, z3, verification, theorem-proving

I want to learn z3 APIs for c++ and how to use them in a c++ program. I tried to find a tutorial but couldn't.
Where can I learn that from? Any tutorial or something? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Z3 distribution contains an example for the Z3 C++ API.
The example is located at `examples/c++/example.cpp`. You can also find it online [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/c++/example.cpp).
The Z3 C++ API is just a thin layer on top of the Z3 C API. It basically provides smart pointers for managing Z3 objects, and overloads operators to simplify how expressions are created. You can find documentation for these APIs [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/index.html).

Remark: it is much easier to learn the Z3 API using Python. A Z3 tutorial based on Python is available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide).